# I cannot assign a script to my prefab in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to get my prefab as soon as it is instantiated to assign this script but I have looked around a lot and I have only been getting some vague answers this following script is on the prefab:

```
public float speed;
public float lifeTime;
public float distance;

public ShootingMechanic ShootScript;

public LayerMask whatIsSolid;

private void Start()
{
    ShootScript = GameObject.Find("gun").GetComponent<ShootingMechanic>();
    Invoke("DestroyProjectile", lifeTime);
}
void DestroyProjectile()
{
    //Instantiate(DestroyEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    Destroy(gameObject);
}

public void Update()
{
    
    transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.up, distance, whatIsSolid);
    if(hitInfo.collider != null)
    {
        if (hitInfo.collider.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            DestroyProjectile();
            hitInfo.collider.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(ShootScript.damagePerShot);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're posting incomplete code, and your question is vague, edit it.

Comment: This code doesnt instantiate anything.

Answer (score 0):

the only place your intantiate something in your givin script is in the Destroyed method, and even there it is //commented.
Feel free to delete this question

Comment: Well you see i have another script that grabs from this script like a "stat hub" or something like that therefore i want to assign this script to  so i can grab a variable to be able to edit things from my "stat hub"

Comment: do you know the purpose of "public" variables? or Static ones? these are all different for exmaple you use public variables when you want to read and change it inside another script, private variables you use when you dont want to change or read it out of the script, and static variables are for only reading it inside another script.

Comment: Wait, i did not realize that, took a moment to sink in but i will try to use static variables when i get the opportunity!